# Should I keep my Jquery and PHP validation separate or use ajax somehow?

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I need to validate two number fields, then multiply/ add together using php (keep calculators private). Finally, return this number into a third 'total field'.

Should I use my Jquery & PHP validation together with ajax some how? Or should I keep my Jquery & PHP validation separate, like the example below: ?

**Jquery validation:**

```
 function mp_calcs_display() {
        $output = <<<HTML
    <form action="" method="post" name="formsubmit" id="formsubmit"   >
    Number of welds: <input type="number" name="numberofwelds" id="numberofwelds"  >
    Number of construction welds: <input type="number" name="numberofconwelds" id="numberofconwelds"  >
    Total time(secs): <input type="text" name="totaltimesecs" disabled>
    <input type="submit"  value="Calculate" id="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('#formsubmit').validate({
            rules:  {

            numberofwelds: "required",
            numberofconwelds: "required"
                    },

            messages: {
            numberofwelds: "Please enter the number of welds",
            numberofconwelds: "Please enter number of con"
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
            }       

        });

        });

        </script>
    HTML;

        return $output;
    }
```

**PHP validation like this:**

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmit'])){
```

then make sure both are numbers & not empty. Then do the calculations in php

Comment: It depends. Do you want to reload the page or not. both are perfectly valid solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always validate your forms *both* in the client and on the server-side.

Client side validation is simply for user experience. It's just really easy on your users to respond quickly and seemlessly with error information versus another page load. When the request is sent off to your server, regardless of javascript validation, you will still need to check again to ensure the request has not been manipulated.

Server side validation is where it counts. Always do this.

**Simple answer: Keep both.**

*Edit: To better answer your question, use AJAX if you can -- it's a better user experience versus reloading the page.*

Comment: I was under the impressions he WAS going to do both either way, just, either done via ajax, or a postback.

Comment: @KevinB Perhaps you are correct and I did misinterpret the question. I do agree with your comment that the answer really depends on if the page needs to be reloaded or not. The better user experience would be to use AJAX.